# How do prepopulate a Field Type Postal Address with values from a user profile

Tags: 7, users, entities

I'm using address field module (addressfield-7.x-1.2) and I don't know how to prepopulate the address field from users profile2 (profile2-7.x-1.3) addressfield  I managed to prepopulate other single fields using tokens